# php and page id - how to?

Tags: php, sql

I've just begun to learn PHP and there is something that is bugging me. I often see php pages, which load content the following way:

```
index.php?id=16
```

What does this mean? Is there a single `index.php` file and the content of a different file (in this case 16) is loaded into this page? Is this advantageous?

And: how do I create such id-pages?

I've already googled it and made a search here, but couldn't find any answers...

If you could simply tell me how this function is called it would already help me a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a query string which can be used by code in the page to load specific content.

Comment: how we implement in any page for exp see the link http://www.bhak1.at/index.php?id=16

Comment: You may capture the query string by using two public arrays, $_GET and $_POST, depending on the method used to send the request to the server.

Comment: this is not about PHP, you should know how to send or get parameters through `GET`.

Comment: @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. They are not `public` arrays, they are `global`. And query string parameters can be accessed with `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST`.. Not by `$_POST`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Good correction, @b0s3!

Comment: Read about *query string* & how they works. And also about `get` requests.

Comment: Sorry @b0s3, but the $_POST exists: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @b0s3, **$_REQUEST** is just a compilation of **$_GET**, **$_POST** and **$_COOKIE**

Comment: @EdvaldoAlmeidaJr. You can't access query string with `$_POST`.

Comment: Yes, you can, @b0s3, if the request was sent with method POST via AJAX, for instance. But if you don`t think, so, it`s well for me. This is not the right place for discussions. Just ask yourself where do you access these variables when coming from a POST request. Then read PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 1):

This means you are calling your index.php file, and you pass it a parameter called `id` with the value `16`. You can access this value like this

```
$_GET['id']
```

It allows you to have dynamic content in your page for example.

Comment: <?php 
$id = @$_GET['id']; // @ will stop error if id is empty 

if(empty($id) || $id > 3) { // if id is empty or bigger then 3 
   include_once("homepage.php); 
} else { 
   switch ($id) { 
       case 1:  include_once("page1.php"); break; 
       case 2:  include_once("page2.php"); break; 
       case 3:  include_once("page3.php"); break; 
   } 
} 
?>

Comment: how we do this task in our own page

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.